# Show only fields that had no duplicates from one column in another

Tags: excel

Lets say I have column A with the following values..

```
02143
02143
04054
04054
04113
04153
04153
04274
04579
04579
04751
04751
04815
05125
```

I need to be able to show ONLY the values that aren't actually duplicated column A. The end result for this column should only show the returns of..

```
04113
04274
04815
05125
```

I would like to show the above resulting "non-duplicated" values in its own Column, such as Column C

Comment: Also put `Column C` data. It should be done in many ways.

Comment: Duplicate means what? `Column A` data are not exist in `column C`?

Comment: I said what I needed incorrectly.  basically only wanted to show the ones that DON'T have duplicates in Column A and put the resulting "non duplicate values" in column C

Comment: If it is a one time job you can simply copy all column to column c and use remove duplicates for column c. If it is a dynamic list, you can try this work: [dynamically remove duplicates](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=97:remove-duplicates-or-create-a-list-of-unique-records-using-excel-formula&catid=77&Itemid=473)

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1:A14)=1,ROW(A1:A14),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

***Screenshot:***
[image]